# Tkinter giving white frame when going from one init-function to separating code into different functions

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I am building an app using tkinter in Python. I started off with a code where everything is written under the init-function. This code worked fine.

As having everything in init was not optimal, I tried separating the code into other functions so that I wouldn't have to duplicate the code when wanting to do the same thing again. When doing so, however, I only get a blank window when executing the program. Can anyone help me identify what the problem is? It's my first time working with tkinter.

My code with everything under **init** looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        """ Creating root and frame widgets """
        self.root = root
        root.title("No Rain App - Happy Test Reporting")

        # Initializing style
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='#2E3135')

        """ Creating mainframe """
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="8 8 24 24", relief="groove")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=EW)
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        """ Creating a greeting's textbox at top """
        greet = "Hello,"
        intro = "Dummy text here that mentions important features of the app." \
                "\nDum du dum dum du dum dum dum." \
        end = "/The No Rain App"
        text = [greet, intro, end]

        for n, t in enumerate(text, start=0):
            if n == 0:
                font1=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 16)
                yaxis = 5
            else:
                font1=("Verdana", 13)
                yaxis=1
            textBox = ttk.Label(mainframe, text=t, background='#2E3135', foreground='white', font=font1)
            textBox.grid(column=1, columnspan=9, row=n+1, padx=10, pady=yaxis, sticky=W)

        base = len(text)

        """ Creates empty space between widgets """
        row = base + 1
        space = ttk.Label(mainframe, text=" \n ", background='#2E3135')
        space.grid(column=9, row=row)

        """ Entry widget for creating jql-query """
        input1 = "Enter name of main folder in summary:"
        input2 = "Enter name of sub folder in summary:"
        inputs = [input1, input2]

        font1 = ("MS Sans Serif", 12)
        font2 = ("Lucida Sans Typewriter", 11)

        self.summary = StringVar()
        self.subsum = StringVar()
        variables = [self.summary, self.subsum]

        entries = []

        row = base + 2
        for n, var in enumerate(variables, start=0):
            n += 0
            for i in inputs:
                sum_label = ttk.Label(mainframe, text=inputs[n], background='#2E3135', foreground='white', font=font1)
                sum_label.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=EW)
            en = Entry(mainframe, textvariable=var, bd=3, background="#484D51", fg='white', font=font2, width=20, relief='flat')
            en.grid(column=2, row=row, sticky=EW)
            en.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
            row += 1
            n += 1
            entries.append(en)
            print(entries)
            print(inputs)

        entries[0].focus()

        # Exit program
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=9, row=row+1)


root = Tk()
Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

After rewriting the code I got:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Gui:

    # Text arrays
    _variables: list
    _entries: list
    _text: list

    def __init__(self, root):
        """ Initiating root and variables"""

        self.root = root
        root.title("No Rain App - Happy Test Reporting")
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='#2E3135')

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="8 8 24 24", relief="groove")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=EW)
        self.mainframe = mainframe
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.subsum = None
        self.summary = None

        def greetings(self):
            """ Creates a greeting's textbox at top """

            greet = "Hello,"
            intro = "Dummy text here that mentions important features of the app." \
                    "\nDum du dum dum du dum dum dum." \
            end = "/The No Rain App"
            self._text = [greet, intro, end]

            for n, t in enumerate(self._text, start=0):
                if n == 0:
                    font1 = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 16)
                    yaxis = 5
                else:
                    font1 = ("Verdana", 13)
                    yaxis = 1
                text_box = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=t, background='#2E3135', foreground='white', font=font1)
                text_box.grid(column=1, columnspan=9, row=n + 1, padx=10, pady=yaxis, sticky=W)

            base = len(self._text)
            return base

        def space(self, n):
            """ Generating empty space between widgets """

            row = self.greetings() + n
            space = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=" \n ", background='#2E3135')
            space.grid(column=9, row=row)

        def jql_query(self):
            """ Entry widget for creating jql-query """

            self.space(1)

            input1 = "Enter name of main folder in summary:"
            input2 = "Enter name of sub folder in summary:"
            inputs = [input1, input2]

            font1 = ("MS Sans Serif", 12)
            font2 = ("Lucida Sans Typewriter", 11)

            self.summary = StringVar()
            self.subsum = StringVar()
            self._variables = [self.summary, self.subsum]
            self._entries = []

            row = self.greetings() + 2
            for n, var in enumerate(self._variables, start=0):
                n += 0
                for i in inputs:
                    sum_label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=inputs[n], background='#2E3135', foreground='white', font=font1)
                    sum_label.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=EW)
                en = Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=var, bd=3, background="#484D51", fg='white', font=font2, width=20, relief='flat')
                en.grid(column=2, row=row, sticky=EW)
                en.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
                row += 1
                n += 1
                self._entries.append(en)
                print(self._entries)
                print(inputs)

            self._entries[0].focus()
            return self._entries

        def __exit__(self):
            """ Exit program"""

            row = self.greetings() + 3
            ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Quit", command=self.root.destroy).grid(column=9, row=row)


root = Tk()
gui = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation of *other functions* make them nested functions inside `__init__()` which I don't think it is what you want.  Also those functions have never been executed.

Comment: Thank you! I tried without indentation first, but the result was the same because, as you said, I didn't call the functions (stupid me). Solved!